# Centering an image link inside of a <td> tag

Tags: html, image, css, html-table, centering

I've looked at W3Schools and several threads here, and no matter what I do, these image links will not center inside of their  elements. I can't just make the  smaller, because some of the images further down in the table just barely fit in the their cells. I would like to both center horizontally, and vertically the images and everywhere I look, the following is how it is said to do it (Well. The horizontal. I figured I'd tackle the vertical centering once I got this straightened out.)

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: (some pixellage amount)
```

For some reason, this is not working in my html/css. Here is one of the links I'm trying to center, and the css codes referencing it.

***HTML***

```
<table class = "displayTable"><tr>
<td class = "photodisplaytd chana">
<a href="chanasImages/Originals/animeApronOriginal.jpg"><img src="chanasImages/animeApron.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='chanasImages/animeApronBack.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='chanasImages/animeApron.jpg'" alt = "Anime styled white apron, front with back image on mouse rollover."/></a>
</td>
```

***CSS***

```
.chana
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:50px;
}

.displayTable
{
alignment: right;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}


.photodisplaytd
{
border:4px solid slategrey;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle where it works with the old style text-align: centre; tech, on the photodisplaytd: http://jsfiddle.net/C6Zux/2/

```
.photodisplaytd
{
    border:4px solid slategrey;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also tried to do it with @cincodenada's suggestion but probably made some mistake and failed so far - that declaration is commented out in the css there now.

Comment: Heya! That worked! Thanks! I didn't think text-align would work on images. Is it because it's technically a link that it does?

Comment: I think text-align works because it actually means aligning of all content and not just text. But is the old way so cincodenada's should be better, I check it now too :)

Comment: ok cincodenada's tech worked finally for me too when added also the width to the a. seems a bit involved though to need to put the image width in the css just for centring, the old way seem simpler (i don't actually know what's wrong with it). here's a version of my fiddle changed to cincodenada's technique anyhow, thanks for teaching that! http://jsfiddle.net/C6Zux/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have the auto margins on everything except where you need them.  [`margin:auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) gives the targeted object automatic margins to center it in its parent.

As a result, you need to apply `margin:auto` to your links themselves (`.chana a`, for instance), not to the table cell or table.  It's not a property of the table cell (like the old align attributes would be), but of the thing being centered.

Additionally, since `a` elements are [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) by default, you have to make them block elements in order to have auto margins.  You can do this by adding a `display: block` to the styles as well.

I put together a quick [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmKEb/1/) showing everything working as expected.

Comment: Even applying the .chana class directly to the a element, it still does not center with margins left and right set to auto.

Comment: My bad, <a> elements are inline by default, but for auto margins they need to be block elements.  Add `display:block` to the styles to force them to block display, and you should be good to go.